Proper velocity and proper acceleration, special relativity
I know there are already multiple threads regarding proper velocity and proper acceleration; I've read through a bunch of them but none clears up my confusion, so please don't collapse this question :)
1/ I am wondering if you can treat proper velocity and proper acceleration in special relativity similarly to classical mechanics, i. e.
Proper velocity(relative to "rest" frame before acceleration) = Proper Acceleration *  Time(traveler).
(for simplicity, let's consider only uniform acceleration in one direction, and time elapsed on traveler's clock from the instant he starts accelerating).
My understanding is that, despite its name, Proper velocity always assumes some reference "rest" frame from which it is measured, and calculated as the distance traveled measured in this rest frame divided by the time measured in the traveler's frame.
2/ How is proper acceleration related to distance traveled in the "Rest" frame (i. e. the frame where the spaceship was at rest, before it started accelerating)? Let's say that a spaceship is at rest in a Rest frame, and wants to travel to a distant star that is 1000 light years away as measured in this Rest frame and not moving relative to the spaceship.
The spaceship starts accelerating at 1g (10 m/s2) towards the star - after 30 000 000 seconds (roughly 1 year), will the ship's proper speed be 300 000 000 m/s (i. e. speed of light, c, relative to the Rest frame)? Such at least is my impression described in point 1 above.
After 10 years of spaceship time, the spaceship should reach proper speed of 10c. If it turned off its engines and coasted to the destination star, this would imply it is covering 10 light-years in Rest frame distance for each year that passes on the spaceship. Since the star's distance in Rest frame is 1 000 LY, the trip should take a bit more than 100 years as measured on the spaceship (allowing for some corrections due to the fact that the trip would not have uniform speed due to acceleration and deceleration at the start and destination).
This however seems to be an incorrect way to think about the situation, as wikipedia article on space travel under constant acceleration says that a ship with 1g constant acceleration could travel 100 000 LY (diameter of our galaxy) in 12 years of ship's time, which is a huge difference to 100+ years calculated for a much shorter 1 000 LY trip above. So I'm getting something very wrong.
I hope that from the above it is clear what my understanding is, and somebody will be able to point out where I went wrong - ideally in plain terms. As should be obvious by now, I'm just at a pop-sci level with rather superficial knowledge of special relativity.
It seems to me that similar scenarios with constant acceleration would be helpful for me to tie the loose ends and get a better understanding of special relativity.

“distance travelled in the rest frame” - you mean zero? In the rest frame of any object, it covers no distance, by definition, since in its rest frame it is not moving (at rest). Also, in calculating the final velocity of the ship, keep in mind that in the rest frame it’s apparent acceleration begins to go down as its velocity approaches lightspeed. The total velocity change can’t be greater than/equal to $c$ even in the limiting case of proper acceleration time going to infinity,

@controlgroup By Rest frame I meant frame the spaceship is in prior to accelerating. So as it starts moving (accelerates), it starts traveling distance in this Rest frame (which is no longer its rest frame after it starts moving, obviously). I'll try to edit the question to make it clearer.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_velocity is pretty good. As you can see, hyperbolic functions feature prominently. Also see https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html

@PM 2Ring Yeah, I've chewed through that a couple of times as well, but frankly I got a bit lost in the math and geometry. I can't say it helped me much in terms of getting a real understanding of what is going on.

Ah, ok. The hyperbolic geometry of Minkowski spacetime isn't very intuitive, but it's unavoidable if you want a real understanding of what's going on. OTOH, you can just use the equations on the Relativistic Rocket page to calculate stuff without fully understanding how they're derived. If you do want to know how they're derived, you need to understand the Lorentz transformations, the relativistic velocity addition formula, and some calculus.

@PM 2Ring Was afraid so... The Lorentz transformations, relativistic velocity addition, time dilation/length contraction and calculus do not scare me :) though "hyperbolic geometry" sounds a bit unapproachable. What I think I was trying to get to was replacing my obviously faulty naive understanding of proper speed = proper acceleration * proper time with the correct version, including some feeling for how we got there.

Hyperbolic geometry is essential for understanding SR.  Think of it as a "hypotenuse" with a minus sign instead of a plus - this new "hypotenuse" is the proper time between two events. There is even a computer game for exploring hyperbolic (spatial, not spacetime) geometry - Hyperrogue: https://roguetemple.com/z/hyper/

@m4r35n357 thanks, the game is neat! Although I can't say it helped me much in understanding of the topic... maybe after some more playing. I was hoping for some "intuitive" insight like I got from the light-clock thought experiment that very naturally connects time dilation to motion as different lengths a light pulse travels between mirrors as seen from different reference frames.

Fair enough, but I was just trying to make hyberbolic geometry less "unapproachable" ;)
